# Term for results being similar in relation to each other, but differing is absolute magnitude

Tags: terminology, model-evaluation

I have some results of several methods, applied to two tasks.
Roughly they are on the lines of

- **Task1**

  - Method A: *20%*
  - Method B: *25%*
  - Method C: *40%*
  - Method D: *70%*
  - Method E: *71%*
- **Task2**

  - Method A: *40%*
  - Method B: *48%*
  - Method C: *70%*
  - Method D: *97%*
  - Method E: *96%*

Task 2 is easier than Task 1, so all methods performed better.

I want to express in words (for my summary),
that on the two tasks the performance of the methods were consistent.
In that the relative performance of the methods were the roughly same.
If ranked from best to worse the order is the same except **D** and **E** swap -- but they were very close together anyway.

**Would it be correct/clear to say that "the relative performance of the methods were consistent"?** Is there a better way to express this?

Comment: In your question; is 'method' and 'model' the same ?

Comment: yes. Let me edit it to use the word method everywhere. (The method was "Apply Model X")

Comment: So you have 5 models, and with each model you evaluate each of two tasks ?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: I would not talk about the 'performance' couldn't you say something like: the measurements of the five models on two different tasks are highly correlated (correlation is 0.99) ?

Comment: In the context I am working on, the measurements in question are performance measurements. The method is Apply Model X to Task Y. Each task has several hundred subtasks which can be succeeded at, or failed at. The measure is the portion of subtasks each model/method succeeds at.

For example, Lets say the models were each methods for detecting drugs.  Task A is to detect what drugs 300 people from London have taken. Task B is to detect what drugs 500 people from New York were on.  The performance is how many people (as a percentage) the method/model gets right in each trial.